# Handling trailing slashes in angularUI router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

It's been hours since I started working on this problem and I can't seem to get my head around the solution.

I have an app that may result in users actually typing in the URL. In such cases it is not hard to believe that user might enter a trailing slash. For example,

> www.example.com/users/2  and  www.example.com/edit/company/123

should be treated the same as

> www.example.com/users/2/  and  www.example.com/edit/company/123/

This only needs to done for handling URL routing on the client side. I am not interested in handling trailing slashes in resource/API calls. I am only interested in handling trailing slashed in the browser.

So I researched and found not many answers on the net. Most of them led me to the FAQ section of angular-ui router.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions

Here they tell us to write a rule, which is what I want to do, but it doesn't seem to be working, or maybe I am doing it wrong.

Here's the plunkr where I have added my code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fD9q7L?p=preview

I have added this to my config, the rest of the code is pretty much the basic stuff.

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector, $location) {
  //if last charcter is a slash, return the same url without the slash
  if($location.$$url[length-1] === '/') {
    return $location.$$url.substr(0,$location.$$url.length - 2);
  } else {
    //if the last char is not a trailing slash, do nothing
    return $location.$$url;
  }
});
```

Basically, I want to make the trailing slash optional, ie it's presence or absence on the address bar should have no effect on the state loaded.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a link to working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iPUvob6frwPBsEHZRXow?p=preview)

And this is the updated rule definition:

```
  $urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector, $location) {

    var path = $location.path();
    var hasTrailingSlash = path[path.length-1] === '/';

    if(hasTrailingSlash) {

      //if last charcter is a slash, return the same url without the slash  
      var newPath = path.substr(0, path.length - 1); 
      return newPath; 
    } 

  });
```

And these links will now work properly:

```
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="route2">Route 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/route1/">#/route1/</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/route2/">#/route2/</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/route1" >#/route1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/route2" >#/route2</a></li>
  </ul>
```

*The magic could be defined like this: do return changed value if there is a change... otherwise do nothing...* [see example](http://plnkr.co/edit/iPUvob6frwPBsEHZRXow?p=preview)

Comment: Oops. I was calling the wrong method in $location. :{ Such a noob mistakte

Comment: AFAIK, this will only work when you define this **rule** in each module of your application. Which might be ok, but you end up with duplicate code throughout your client-side Router configurations; if you've separated them out into each module.

Has anyone solved this on an application level?

Comment: @MichaelLeanos, it actually works if you structure your modules in such a way that there is one main module that has all other modules injected. Have a look at this [Yoda source code](https://github.com/yoda-yoda/yoda-face/tree/master/src/app) on GitHub. All you need to do is add your shared functionality to the main config file and it works throughout your Angular app.

Comment: @Cyn you're right. I realized that after I dug deeper into an issue I was having. I have a module named "Core" where I was defining the **Rule**. However, the way my modules are loaded, it was alphabetical. I was specifically testing a module that came before "Core" alphabetically, and the Rule wasn't applied. Then I tested a different module that came after; it worked. So I realized the flaw. I ended up just injecting the "Core" module into each of my other module's as a dependency. Which I believe is what you're describing.

Comment: Yea, that seems like it would work. Not exactly what I meant. In fact, my idea was to inject all of the other modules into the main module, and have a   main base file that is controlled by this main module, so you can always disable an app if you wish, without breaking stuff too much. Here's an example:

Comment: `angular

        .module("learnmine", [
            //  3rd party
            "ui.router",
            "templates-app",
            "templates-common",
            "ngMaterial",
            "ngCookies",

            // my apps
            "learnmine.common",
            "learnmine.auths",
            "learnmine.routes",
            "learnmine.config",
            "learnmine.home",
            "learnmine.dashboard",
            "learnmine.classroom"
        ])
        .controller("learnmine.controllers.main", [...]`  [Nice Indented Code Here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/15278291/)

Comment: For me the issue is, that there is 2 slashes at start `#//route1`. It does work, but wonder what is the issue.

Comment: This is the only thing working for me, despite all the other 'newer' solutions

Answer (score 14):

As of ui-router version [0.2.11](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases/tag/0.2.11) you can do this:

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
```

This will treat URLs with and without trailing slashes identically.

Comment: Also compatible with 1.x versions

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough rep for a comment so making an answer :-

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
```

Needs to be before the `$stateProvider.state` part.

Comment: !IMPORTANT! Needs to be before the $stateProvider.state part.!

Answer (score 4):

`urlMatcherFactoryProvider` is [deprecated](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/1.0.0-rc.1/modules/injectables.html#_urlmatcherfactoryprovider) for **v1.x** of angular-ui-router.

Use `urlService.config.strictMode` ([ng1](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/1.0.0-rc.1/interfaces/url.urlconfigapi.html#strictmode), [ng2](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/interfaces/url.urlconfigapi.html#strictmode)) instead.

It still needs to be before `$stateProvider.state()`.

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlServiceProvider) {
  var homeState = {
    name: 'home',
    url: '/home',
    component: 'xyHome'
  };

  $urlServiceProvider.config.strictMode(false);

  $stateProvider.state(homeState);
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Hi You need to set `strictMode = false`
Angular ui-router provide method for this

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
```

You need to set strict mode before initialising the State `$stateProvider.state({})`

For more details you can refer this [Link](http://www.zippyout.com/blog/58c76355e890296b902966c8/angular-ui-router-trailing-slash-case-sensitive-issue)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by using `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` to handle the cases where the router is unable to match the path.

In the following example, the router is unable to match `/mypath` and therefore calls `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` to find out what to do. Here we can see the path that was requested and map it to the proper path, i.e. `/mypath/`

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
        if ($location.$$path == '/mypath')
            return "/mypath/";
        else
            return "/defaultpath";
    });
```