# AngularJS with ui.router: parameter in URL interpreted as path if trailing slash

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, trailing-slash

In my AngularJS app with ui.router the parameter in the URL is interpreted as path if there is a trailing slash.

What works:

```
http://example.com/product/123
```

What does not work:

```
http://example.com/product/123/
```

In the console I see that AngularJS is looking for all files in
`http://example.com/product/123/` rather in `http://example.com/product`

Google tells there is an option `$urlMatcherFactory.strictMode(false)` I don't have an idea how to get it to work. And still I am not sure if this would help.

Anyone with similar experiences?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420578/handling-trailing-slashes-in-angularui-router

Answer (score 0):

I had no luck with `$urlMatcherFactory.strictMode(false)` and I think that a mixture of a vhost alias and a conditional htaccess RewriteBase caused some conflict that I was not able to figure out within five hours.

What I now did, and this works well:

On the very top of the index.html I put this script:

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.slice(-1) == '/') {
    window.location.href = url.substring(0, url.length - 1);
}
```

So in case a user or browser adds a trailing slash, the page reloads without the trailing slash.

That's fine for know, still hoping to catch the culprit and fix it someday instead of sailing around it.