# ui-router adding trailing slash at end of route causing 404

Tags: angularjs, apache, angular-ui-router

I've built out an application and mostly everything is working as expected except I have these three states where when I refresh the page via reloading the url it causes a trailing slash on the end of the page causing my otherwise('/404') to trigger.

This happen nowhere else on the entire platform. The weird part is that if I change the state URL for one of the states with issues, the issue is fixed.

The three state url's that have issues are `market`, `refer-business` and `invite-friends`. These are all a child of a shell view named `root`. I have absolutely no idea what is causing this issue.

I also realized that if I take `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');` out of my main modules config, the issue goes away as well.

Here are two of the routes that aren't working.

market.routes.js

```
  function marketRoutes($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('market', {
      parent: 'root',
      url: '/market?category', // If I change this to /blahblah, it works perfects
      views: {
        "@root": {
          templateUrl: '/market/market.html',
          controller: 'MarketController',
          controllerAs: 'MarketCtrl'
        }
      },
      resolve: {
        Categories: ['MarketService', function (MarketService) {
          return MarketService.getCategories();
        }],
        Products: ['MarketService', '$stateParams', function (MarketService, $stateParams) {
          // By default the market should open on `deals of the moment` category
          return MarketService.getProducts(0, 9, 1, $stateParams.category || 4);
        }]
      },
      data: {
        title: 'Market'
      }
    });
  }
```

refer-business.routes.js

```
  function ReferBusinessRoutes($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('refer-business', {
      parent: 'root',
      url: "/refer",
      templateUrl: "/refer-business/refer-business.html",
      controller: "ReferBusinessController",
      controllerAs: "rbCtrl",
      onEnter: function () {
        this.data.title = "Refer a business";
      },
      data: {
        title: 'Refer a business'
      },
      authenticate: true
    });
  }
```

I've spent the last 3 days on this and I've come up with nothing. Hopefully somebody here has run into this issue or has some tips on how to further debug it.

Comment: sounds like server config issue

Comment: Any idea how to debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find the answer here: [Handling trailing slashes in angularUI router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420578/handling-trailing-slashes-in-angularui-router)

Explains How to tell angular deal with trailing slashes as usual.

It  also might be permission problem in your template files at server side