# ui-router states conflicting with / is added

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Basically,

state 1:

```
 myurl.com/:id/:other
```

state 2:

```
 myurl.com/:id
```

So far so good... but if we do:

```
myurl.com/:id/
```

The state will look for state 1 with :other missing parameter instead going state 2.

Ant thoughts?

**UPDATE**

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
```

Does not work if you have a query parameter, meaning if:

```
myurl.com/:id/:product
```

and you deleted /:product i will fetch for empty value.

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector, $location) {

    var path = $location.path();
    var hasTrailingSlash = path[path.length-1] === '/';

    if(hasTrailingSlash) {

      //if last charcter is a slash, return the same url without the slash  
      var newPath = path.substr(0, path.length - 1); 
      return newPath; 
    } 

  });
```

Kind of do the job but if you delete the final wildcard and try to go a inner level, it will stay in upper level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling trailing slashes in angularUI router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420578/handling-trailing-slashes-in-angularui-router)

Comment: You could check through `$routeParam.others` is if null or empty, redirect to   State2

Comment: almost but nope! thxs for the advice anyhow @JohnSmith -

Comment: not and escalable solution cause I have more than 2 states to verify @Dev-One

Comment: Did you try regex parameters, i.e: myurl.com/{id:[^/]+}/{other:[]^/+} ?