# angularjs routing with slash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

In the following AngularJS/Ui-router example I have a nav leading to 2 state:

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>
    <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
    <a ui-sref="news">News</a>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>


app.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url : '/home',
    template: '<h1>Home page</h1>'
  });

  $stateProvider.state('news', {
    url : '/news',
    template: '<h1>News page</h1>'
  });
});
```

Yeah, everything works fine in general as you already know. Hitting the news link will call the news state and so on.

BUT, suppose your user goes into the browser navigator and writes:

**WEBSITEURL/news/** by adding a slash */* at the end!

OH NOOOO! It won't redirect to **WEBSITEURL/news**

Why **/news** works and **/news/** doesn't work?

In general, why **/uri** works and **/uri/** doesn't work?

That's not logical at all. What is a good solution to get out of this?!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420578/handling-trailing-slashes-in-angularui-router

Answer (score 1):

Add a new rule for your `ui-router` configuration:

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector, $location) {
    var path = $location.path();
    if(path[path.length-1] === '/';) {
       var newPath = path.substr(0, path.length - 1); 
       return newPath
    } 

});
```

So, your code becomes,

```
app.config(function($stateProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector, $location) {
        var path = $location.path();
        if(path[path.length-1] === '/';) {
          var newPath = path.substr(0, path.length - 1); 
          return newPath
        } 

    }); 

    $stateProvider.state('home', {
      url : '/home',
      template: '<h1>Home page</h1>'
    });

    $stateProvider.state('news', {
      url : '/news',
      template: '<h1>News page</h1>'
    });
});
```